# Create table category_path opencart 1.5.6.4

Tags: mysql, opencart

I have a problem. When I try to edit something in the category area of my opencart isntallation an error shows up saying the table category_path does not exist.

This error usually happens when an upgrade went wrong. Can I simply use a `CREATE_TABLE` query in my phpmyadmin to fix this, or would that not work?

Hope someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to create the category path table it can be created like this (replacing `oc_` with your database prefix if necessary):

```
CREATE TABLE `oc_category_path` (
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `path_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `level` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`,`path_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
```

You can run that SQL from phpMyAdmin or any other MySQL client.  Afterward you can navigate to the Admin > Catalog > Category and click `Repair` which should generate the necessary records.

Please note, that table is generated by install/upgrade script and it's exactly as you say, probably a botched database upgrade or none at all.  If that's the case, bear in mind that you may have other database problems as well and you may benefit by running the upgrade script on your database.